# Xenserver - Access guest VM directly from host

Tags: desktop, virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I've got a decent PC that I'd like to install xenserver on, but it's also my primary workstation. Wondering if it's possible to access guests directly from the host machine -- meaning, can I use the monitor, input devices, etc that are attached to the host, to interact with the guests.

Currently setup as a dual boot Linux and Windows machine. I need them both running simultaneously while still being able to treat the host like a workstation. Already using Virtualbox, which is great but not what I'm aiming for.

I've searched high and low for an answer to this question. Maybe I wasn't searching with the right terms. I've found a package in the Ubuntu repos that adds an entry in grub along the lines of 'Ubuntu with Xen Hypervisor', but that was on a test machine that couldn't actually run Xen.

Normally, I'd just wipe this puppy and find out for myself, but there are really good reasons why I can't just jump into it this time, so I'm turning to the community.

Thanks for any and all info!

Comment: Relevant: I run graphics-intensive applications in both OSes that rely on the GPU. I know this complicates things. If it's all possible except for access to the graphics card, that's still a win in my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple text console on the host to interact with the guests

`xe console vm=guest`

but I don't know of a way to access a graphical interface from the host.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I've given up the dream, but this is still useful info.